# Get all links from page on Wikipedia

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler

I am making a Python web-crawler program to play [The Wiki game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wiki_Game).

If you're unfamiliar with this game:

1. Start from some article on Wikipedia
2. Pick a goal article
3. Try to get to the goal article from the start article just by clicking wiki/ links

My process for doing this is:

1. Take a start article and a goal article as input
2. Get a list of articles that link to the goal article
3. Preform a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) on the links found avoiding pages that have already been visited starting from the start article
4. Check if the goal article is on the current page: If it is, then return the `path_crawler_took+goal_article`
5. Check if any  of the articles that link to the goal are on the current page. If one of them is, return `path_crawler_took+intermediate_article+goal`

I was having a problem where the program would return a path, but the path wouldn't really link to the goal.

```
def get_all_links(source):
    source = source[:source.find('Edit section: References')]
    source = source[:source.find('id="See_also"')]
    links=findall('\/wiki\/[^\(?:/|"|\#)]+',source)
    return list(set(['http://en.wikipedia.org'+link for link in links if is_good(link) and link]))

links_to_goal = get_all_links(goal)
```

I realized that I was getting the links to the goal by scraping all of the links off of the goal page, but wiki/ links are unidirectional: Just because the goal links to a page doesn't mean that page links to the goal.

How can I get a list of articles that link to the goal?

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia back-links tool http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Backlink

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia has a built in tool that does just what you are describing [WhatLinksHere/Backlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Backlink).

You can see this tool on every Wikipedia page.
[image: Example]

You can simply scrape all of the links off the page of goal's the back-links page.

```
'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3AWhatLinksHere&limit='500'&target='+goal+'&namespace=0'
                                                                                          ^^^^
                                                                                          Article you are trying to reach here
```

[Wiki-help page for WhatLinksHere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:What_links_here)